# Using a POST request inside a GET request's call back (Closures)

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

I will demonstrate my problem with this simplified code:

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    let x = req.query.someVar;
    app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
        console.log(x);
    });
    res.send(`Hello ${req.query.someVar}`);
});
```

The first time this code runs, the POST callback function saves a reference to `x` which is whatever I pass as query parameters. if I change the query parameters, send another GET request it will be updated in the server's response i.e.`res.send(`Hello ${req.query.someVar}`);` but a POST request will still log the original `x` value to the console.

Why is it behaving this way? I have tried many things like passing by objects and through other functions, etc..

I am familiar with how closures work, but obviously not entirely as this is most definitely a problem with the POST call back preserving the value of the query parameters and not updating them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do.  No one defines a POST inside of a GET, they do that at the root level, unless you want the GET request to change the behavior of your server.  app.post means 'add a new route to handle a POST'. Perhaps you wanted to actually *send* an HTTP request from the GET handler?

If you want the behavior to change maybe just handle the POST at the root level and set a global flag in the GET handler to indicate that POST should do something different with subsequent requests.

Comment: I am getting information via the query parameters that are needed to query the db on a post request to the same page. So I need the post to have access to the query params

Comment: So in order to do the action the client needs to GET and POST to the same URL?  Never heard of anyone doing it that way.. if you really need to store state you can use a database or something like a global variable, not a closure.  But I think usually you would just send x with the POST request.